# Multiple JavaScript functions not running

Tags: html, javascript

I'm trying to make an app that allows you a text editor. You can type anything in to a text block. You can do two things with said text block:

a) run the text as an html page in a new about:blank tab or

b) save the text as a .html

For some reason, though, when I tried to implement the save ability, neither function would load. If I go into the JS console, it shows me this error upon clicking on the save button:

```
"Uncaught ReferenceError: saveAsFile is not defined (temp.html,1)"
```

When I seperated them into two `<script>` blocks, I could get the save function to work. However, when I did that, the Run in New Tab function no longer worked. It was utterly confusing.

I have used multiple functions before, and I don't know why it's suddenly not working. Can someone help? This is my code:

```
<script>
function run() {
var codeTab = window.open("" _blank);
var codeRun = document.getElementById("code").value;
codeTab.document.write(codeRun);
}
</script>
<script>
/*i stole-i mean used-this code from someone else*/
function saveAsFile() {
var textToSave = document.getElementById("code").value;

var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
hiddenElement.download = 'save.html';
hiddenElement.click();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 3, you have `window.open("" _blank);`. It should be `window.open("_blank");`.

I also cannot see anywhere `saveAs()` is being called (or defined). Is it possibly being called in `codeRun`? See below code which worked for me.

```html
<textarea id="code">

</textarea>
<button onclick="run();">Run</button>
<button onclick="saveAsFile();">Save</button>

<script>
  function run() {
    var codeTab = window.open("_blank");
    var codeRun = document.getElementById("code").value;
    codeTab.document.write(codeRun);
  }

  /*i stole-i mean used-this code from someone else*/
  function saveAsFile() {
    var textToSave = document.getElementById("code").value;

    var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

    hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'save.html';
    hiddenElement.click();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Though this is useful, and I did forget to put `_blank` in quotes, I did intentionally leave those two quotes empty - the first set of quotation marks is for the website url, and leaving those empty defaults to about:blank

Comment: I tried the code you gave and got `ReferenceError: run is not defined` when clicking run. After correcting that, it was working. I can update my answer with the exact code I used if you like.

Comment: @DCowan - You received a different error than what the author received, which is explained by the fact, they left the URL string as an empty string (on purpose).

Comment: Yes. I do notice that I can't see anywhere @thanoschimichan-ga is calling a function or accessing a variable `saveAs`. That does lead me to believe that it may be something in code @thanoschimichan-ga has put in `codeRun`.

Comment: Sorry - saveAs is saveAsFile, I typed it wrong - I'll edit the original post

Comment: surely it's `window.open("", "_blank")` since `_blank` is a special SECOND argument to window.open